# How to map value for array object in Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following structure where I want to assign `Parent.StockNumber` to `Supplier.StockNumber`. Since `Supplier` is array, I am not sure how to use `.ForEach` in Automapper.

Code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EarliestPaymentDate { get; set; }
    public List<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class ParentDto
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EarliestPaymentDate { get; set; }
    public List<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierDto
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper:

```
CreateMap<ParentDto, Parent>()
    // Single value assignment
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EarliestPaymentDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EarliestPaymentDateTime))
    // .Suppliers is an array and not sure how to do mapping here.
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Suppliers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StockNumber))
    ;
```

I tried following, but this is def wrong.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Suppliers.ForEach(x => x.StockNumber), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StockNumber))
```

Comment: What is your `ParentDto` class?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question with `dto`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by using `AfterMap`.

Code:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<ParentDto, Parent>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.EarliestPaymentDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EarliestPaymentDateTime))
        .AfterMap(HandleArrayProperties);

}

private static void HandleArrayProperties(ParentDto parentDto, Parent parent)
{
    parent.Suppliers.ForEach(x => x.StockNumber = Convert.ToInt64(parentDto.StockNumber));
}
```

Comment: Since your `ParentDto` `StockNumber ` property is `long` type, to assign a `long` value to `long` property, you don't need the `Convert.ToInt64()`. `x.StockNumber = parentDto.StockNumber`.